# Problema URL de django 404

Tags: html, python, django

Estoy construyendo una página web con Django, tengo creadas las vistas correspondientes en el archivo **views.py** de tal manera:

```
def index(request):
return render(request, "index.html")

def contact(request):
    return render(request, "contact.html")
```

Lo mismo para el archivo **urls.py**

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.index),
path('index/', views.index),
path('contact/', views.contact),
```

Desde mi archivo **index.html** usé el link de href de la siguiente manera:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact" class="nav-link">Contacto</a></li>
```

Al comienzo, cuando presiono la palabra contacto en el nav todo funciona bien y se muestra la siguiente url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
```

Pero si vuelvo a presionar nuevamente la palabra contacto me sale el error 404 y a la url se le agrega lo siguiente:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/contact.html
```

Mi pregunta es sobre como hacer que la url se vaya sobreescribiendo a medida que la voy presionando, ya que solo me sucede con contacto, cuando presiono la ruta hacia el index esta se me sobreescribe automáticamente

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso esta manera cuando hago href, te pongo un ejemplo de como sería el tuyo.

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'contact' %}" class="nav-  link">Contacto</a></li>
```